# Wordpress single.php shows post title but no content

Tags: php, wordpress, post, blogs

Hi there I was wondering if anyone could assist me quickly.

I am working on a clients site and all of a sudden the blog posts only show the title and not the content.

I am not sure why and need some assistance.

here is the code for the single.php

```
    <div id="primary" class="content-area">

    <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'single' ); ?>


        <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">

    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>



            <?php nightwatch_content_nav( 'nav-below' ); ?>

            <?php
                // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template
                if ( comments_open() || '0' != get_comments_number() )
                    comments_template( '', true );
            ?>

        <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

        </div><!-- #content .site-content -->
    </div><!-- #primary .content-area -->
```

Thank you for your help.

*Edit

Here is the content-single.php code

```
<?php
/**
* @package nightwatch
* @since nightwatch 1.0.2
*/
?>

<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
<header class="entry-header">
    <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

    <div class="entry-meta">
        <?php nightwatch_posted_on(); ?>
    </div><!-- .entry-meta -->
</header><!-- .entry-header -->

<div class="entry-content">
    <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . __(               '    Pages:', 'nightwatch' ), 'after' => '</div>' ) ); ?>
</div><!-- .entry-content -->

<footer class="entry-meta">
    <?php
        /* translators: used between list items, there is a space after the           comma */
        $category_list = get_the_category_list( __( ', ', 'nightwatch' ) );

        /* translators: used between list items, there is a space after the comma */
        $tag_list = get_the_tag_list( '', ', ' );

        if ( ! nightwatch_categorized_blog() ) {
            // This blog only has 1 category so we just need to worry    about tags in the meta text
            if ( '' != $tag_list ) {
                $meta_text = __( 'This entry was tagged %2$s.     Bookmark the <a href="%3$s" title="Permalink to %4$s" rel="bookmark">permalink</a>.',    'nightwatch' );
            } else {
                $meta_text = __( 'Bookmark the <a href="%3$s"   title="Permalink to %4$s" rel="bookmark">permalink</a>.', 'nightwatch' );
            }

        } else {
            // But this blog has loads of categories so we should    probably display them here
            if ( '' != $tag_list ) {
                $meta_text = __( 'This entry was posted in %1$s and    tagged %2$s. Bookmark the <a href="%3$s" title="Permalink to %4$s" rel="bookmark">permalink</a>.', 'nightwatch' );
            } else {
                $meta_text = __( 'This entry was posted in %1$s. 
Bookmark the <a href="%3$s" title="Permalink to %4$s" rel="bookmark">permalink</a>.',   'nightwatch' );
            }

        } // end check for categories on this blog

        printf(
            $meta_text,
            $category_list,
            $tag_list,
            get_permalink(),
            the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' )
        );
    ?>

    <?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'nightwatch' ), '<span class="edit-    link">', '</span>' ); ?>
</footer><!-- .entry-meta -->
</article><!-- #post-<?php the_ID(); ?> -->'
```

Comment: Here is an example http://kaarbontech.co.uk/come-and-see-us-at-mapping-showcase-2013/

Comment: are you sure that this is call from single.php..? it might be page.php...

Comment: yes it is calling from single.php as when I make edits to single.php like putting in breadcrumbs you can see the visible difference on the webpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should include [the_content()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content); in the place you want the content to appear. Something like this:

```
<?php 
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
    the_content();
?>
```

Also, in the file content-single.php comment out (or delete) these lines:

```
<div class="entry-content">
    <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . __(               '    Pages:', 'nightwatch' ), 'after' => '</div>' ) ); ?>
</div><!-- .entry-content -->
```

Comment: Great advice! The only problem now is there are two share button bars and so I feel that the content is being called elsewhere in the code. How can I get rid of the extra social share bar?

Comment: This line get_template_part( 'content', 'single' ); calls an extra file! Can you find it and share it's code?

Comment: Sure I will edit the original message and include the content-post.php code. Thanks for all of your help so far!

Comment: Fantastic! This has worked perfectly and the additional share bar has been deleted!

If possible could you suggest to me why the H1 is not taking the green  font format for headings??

Comment: I'm glad it worked! For the color, go to your style.css file in the line 742 an change color to #90C73E.

Comment: Thank you so much for all of your help! Great support!